# How to remove blue highlight when you hold on input buttons in css?

Tags: html, css

I am making a mobile app, and when I view it on android phone using chrome browser, and hold on the input button (type is `submit` if that matters), I notice a blue highlight around it (like its not a border, its a full rectangle). 
The actual button is within the border and has rounder corners. But for some reason it highlights a rectangle that's blue when I hold on the button. Is there some css that can remove that?

Thanks

Here is a screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this :

```
.button_class:focus {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```